# Strange looking block

Tags: html, css, layout

```
`*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

*,*::before,*:after{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
:focus, :active{outline: none;}
a:focus,a:active{outline: none;}

nav,footer,header,aside{display: block;}

html,body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

input,button,textarea{font-family: inherit;}

input::-ms-clear{display: none;}
button{cursor: pointer;}
button::-moz-focus-inner {padding: 0;border: 0;}
a, a:visited{text-decoration: none;}
a:hover{text-decoration: none;}
ul li{list-style: none;}
img{vertical-align: top;}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size: inherit;font-weight: 400;}

body{
    background: url('css_img/Site_Background.png');
}


.Menu{
    position: absolute;
    width: 569px;
    height: 1132px;
    left: -147px;
    top: -14px;
    
  
}`
```

I am absolute begginer (two days in) and i started doing layout for training from design made in figma by one of my friends. As i understood, to properly pose the block, i should copy and paste in CSS file code from Figma, but it worked for everything, except one block, which gets flatenned. Also i reseted styles, maybe problem is in it?

[css code of style reset and block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5HhH.png)

[strange looking block (flatenned menu sidebar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HUfg.jpg)

Comment: Please post your actual code in a [mcve] in your question, not images of code

Comment: @j08691: Someone will still have to convert the second image to a first-class one.  The OP doesn't have sufficient rep to do that.